# How to cluster one feature value based on another feature value

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

I have a df as follows

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | X |
| 1 | Y |
| 2 | Z |
| 2 | A |
| 3 | B |

I need to have a cluster as follows

[image]

Can anyone please tell me how to do it in python?

Comment: Are you looking for `groupby()`?

Comment: yes. Something like that